# Errors while using catkin_make in ROS inside Raspbian Stretch

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ROS Kinetic (ROS-Comm: (recommended) ROS package, build, and communication libraries. No GUI tools.)  in Raspbian Stretch.

I have already built and run few ROS packages on Ubuntu successfully on my Robot. Now I need to migrate those packages to Raspbian Stretch based ROS. The ROS that I installed in Ubuntu is Melodic. So I might be getting some compatibility issues as I am running ROS Kinetic in Raspbian Stretch. So while I am using the

```
catkin_make_isolated --force-cmake
```

command, I constantly get errors like "Failed to process the package" for different packages like `geometric_shapes`, `move_base_msgs`, `robot_pose_ekf` and the list goes on. I think one of the reason might be that I have installed ROS-Comm that has no GUI Tools, but if that is the case then I do not know how to figure it out whether any particular package is linked to GUI or not.

As I am just a beginner, I am giving the names of the packages that are failing to be processed:

1. geometric_shapes
2. navigation
3. navigation_msgs
4. robot_pose_ekf
5. rosserial

I am eagerly seeking some reference to work on ROS with Raspberry Pi, but I could not find any. If anyone can help me, I would be grateful.

Shaunak

---

Edit: **Ok. I tried just copying the Packages (without compilation) to Raspberry Pi and compile them, but the errors remain. For example currently I am getting the following error text while processing the pacakge "tf2_msgs" during compilation:**

```
 CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "geometry_msgs"
  with any of the following names:

    geometry_msgsConfig.cmake
    geometry_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "geometry_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "geometry_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "geometry_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- Could not find the required component 'geometry_msgs'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "geometry_msgs"
  with any of the following names:

    geometry_msgsConfig.cmake
    geometry_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "geometry_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "geometry_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "geometry_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/catkin_ws/build_isolated/tf2_msgs/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/pi/catkin_ws/build_isolated/tf2_msgs/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
<== Failed to process package 'tf2_msgs': 
  Command '['/home/pi/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/navigation/env.sh', 'cmake', '/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/geometry2/tf2_msgs', '-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/pi/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/tf2_msgs', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/pi/catkin_ws/install_isolated', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/pi/catkin_ws/build_isolated/tf2_msgs && /home/pi/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/navigation/env.sh cmake /home/pi/catkin_ws/src/geometry2/tf2_msgs -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/pi/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/tf2_msgs -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/pi/catkin_ws/install_isolated -G 'Unix Makefiles'

Command failed, exiting.
```

**As I have just started with ROS  on Raspbian Stretch, I need to know whether Raspbian Stretch has the compatibility with ROS or not. If yes, then I am quite amazed why it is not able even to build default packages. I have already built the "hello world" package successfully, so it concluded the ROS installation is valid.**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303858/errors-while-using-catkin_make-in-ros-inside-raspbian-stretch/) by [Shaunak Vyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/37404/shaunak-vyas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2018-09-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-20**:\

> I constantly get errors like "Failed to process the package"

this is too vague.

Please copy-paste a complete error message into your question text.

Use the `edit` button/link for that and please format using the *Preformatted Text* button (with `101010` on it).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-20**:
Also, what does this mean:

> Now I need to migrate those packages to Raspbian Stretch based ROS.

exactly? Do you just want to *build* the same pkgs on your rpi, or are you attempting to *copy* compiled pkgs from your desktop pc to your rpi?

**Comment by [Shaunak Vyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/37404/shaunak-vyas/) on 2018-09-20**:
I am attempting to copy compiled pkgs from desktop PC to RPi.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-20**:\

> I am attempting to copy compiled pkgs from desktop PC to RPi.

then that is part of your problem.

You cannot do that.

Your PC and your RPi use different CPU architectures (most likely `amd64` vs `ARM`). Binary artefacts cannot be copied. You'll have to compile them on the RPi *or* use a ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-20**:
.. cross-compiler on your PC.

**Comment by [luk.mitka](https://answers.ros.org/users/37135/luk.mitka/) on 2018-09-21**:
Above error means that `geometry_msgs` package probably is not installed or it cannot be found.
Does `rospack find geometry_msgs` return path to package?
If no you will need to install it before you can build your other packages.

**Comment by [Shaunak Vyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/37404/shaunak-vyas/) on 2018-09-21**:
Ohh. Very True. I have have not installed the packages. Actually, when I installed ROS-Melodic in Ubuntu (PC), I got the packages as it was a full install.

**Comment by [Shaunak Vyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/37404/shaunak-vyas/) on 2018-09-21**:
But in Raspbian Stretch, I have installed the recommended ROS-Comm: which is an ROS package that has build, and communication libraries and No GUI tools.

**Comment by [Shaunak Vyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/37404/shaunak-vyas/) on 2018-09-21**:
How can I install any randomly required package in ROS now? The command `git clone https://github.com/ros/geometry2.git`   get the package but the same compilation error remains.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-21**:
Please see #q252478 for the general procedure for how to build things from source.

On your RPi however, you might need to build more pkgs from source, as `rosdep` might not be able to install the required pkgs itself.

In that case, look at `rosinstall_generator`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-21**:\

> I have already built the "hello world" package successfully, so it concluded the ROS installation is valid

You cannot conclude that from your simple test.

Building pkgs is not a trivial process and it takes some skill. Please try to read up on it and make sure to take dependencies into account.

**Comment by [Boregard](https://answers.ros.org/users/33549/boregard/) on 2018-09-22**:
I used ubuntu mate 16.04 on raspberry and installed ros (desktop full) like a normal installation.
Everything worked finde so far (got some tutorials running).
Import for catkin compile are the following statements:

$  sudo swapoff -a
   $  catkin_make -j1

**Comment by [Shaunak Vyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/37404/shaunak-vyas/) on 2018-09-23**:
I am using RPi 3B+ which does not support Ubuntu Mate. So I am switching to Xubuntu 16.04. Let's see where I end up. Does ROS get installed in Xubuntu the same way as it is installed in Ubuntu Mate?

**Comment by [Boregard](https://answers.ros.org/users/33549/boregard/) on 2018-09-25**:
I used the normal installation procedure for ubuntu mate - therefore I guess you can use the same way for Xubuntu.
The only thing that was special on mate was the missing build-essentials. You can install them by:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential -y
```

Just double check your Xubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**@gvdhoorn : Thank you for sharing #q252478. I followed the execution steps to install geometry2 package, but I am getting the following error:**

---

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/catkin_ws $ rosdep install --from-paths src/ --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic
```

ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
tf2_geometry_msgs: No definition of [orocos_kdl] for OS [debian]
tf2_bullet: No definition of [geometry_msgs] for OS [debian]
tf2_sensor_msgs: No definition of [geometry_msgs] for OS [debian]
tf2_eigen: No definition of [geometry_msgs] for OS [debian]
test_tf2: No definition of [tf] for OS [debian]
tf2_ros: No definition of [geometry_msgs] for OS [debian]
tf2: No definition of [geometry_msgs] for OS [debian]
tf2_msgs: No definition of [geometry_msgs] for OS [debian]
tf2_kdl: No definition of [orocos_kdl] for OS [debian]

---

**So, I think I am running debian based Raspbian Stretch which is creating the issue. But Ubuntu is also based on debian. Still, should I switch to Xubuntu, Ubuntu Mate or Snappy Ubuntu Core? If yes, which one would be the best for ROS?**

---

Originally posted by [Shaunak Vyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/37404/shaunak-vyas/) with karma: 17 on 2018-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shaunak Vyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/37404/shaunak-vyas/) on 2018-09-23**:
The Stretch seems not working well with ROS. I am switching to Xubuntu 16.04. Let's see where I end up. Does ROS get installed in Xubuntu the same way as it is installed in Ubuntu Mate?

**Comment by [Shaunak Vyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/37404/shaunak-vyas/) on 2018-09-25**:
I have written RaspEx image to Pi 3B+ Memory Card (Reference:  https://sourceforge.net/projects/raspex/)
Now I am trying to install ROS on RaspEx. I am using this link for that: https://www.intorobotics.com/how-to-install-ros-kinetic-on-raspberry-pi-3-ubuntu-mate/ ........

**Comment by [Shaunak Vyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/37404/shaunak-vyas/) on 2018-09-25**:
........because I could not find any link that can help me to install ROS on RaspEx. I kindly request to help as soon as possible because I am really stuck up in ROS on Raspberry Pi 3 B+.

**Comment by [Shaunak Vyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/37404/shaunak-vyas/) on 2018-09-25**:
I do not know why but Raspberry Pi 3 B+ is turning out to be a headache for me due to its arm64 architecture which do not support the OS in which ROS can be fully functional.

**Comment by [Shaunak Vyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/37404/shaunak-vyas/) on 2018-09-28**:
Finally I have successfully installed Xubuntu in Raspberry Pi and it resolved all the issues. The robot is fully functional now. I kindly request to close this ticket.